# Facebook Requests Dialog - is it possible to work in page tab app?

Tags: php, facebook

I am building a fan page tab application in facebook and I have encountered the problem that Request Dialog (the one that invites your friends) does not work in a page tab. The dialog appears, I select the friends, I receive in the log that invites are sent,but people do not receive them. The app is not in sandbox and I am testing with real users (not test users).

I read this facebook policy:

Requests are only available for games on Facebook.com or iOS and Android apps. Accepting a request from a game will direct the person to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request. For native mobile apps, accepting the request will direct the person to the app on their device if installed or to the appropriate location (Apple App Store or Google Play) to download the app otherwise.

Does this mean that it is no longer available for page tab apps and only canvas apps can use this? I recently saw a page tab app which uses this, which is contradictory.

Any tips regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use requests *for* page tab apps, only for canvas apps.

That does not mean, that you can’t use the requests dialog *in* a page tab app – but the app must have a canvas set up as well so that there is something that the users accepting the request can be send to. (From there you could redirect to a specific page tab if you like.)

Comment: Yes, I did setup a canvas app along with the page tab (until now I didn't know that an app can act like both) and it worked. Users receive the request to the canvas app and then the canvas app redirects to the page tab app. Thanks mate!